# Running Rails on a private server

Tags: dns, dyndns

The issue I'm having is a bit hard to explain.. I Recently took it upon myself to learn Rails. I've got a server (a computer with ubuntu 12.04 running at my house) And own a domain with Hover.com, and use no-IP as a dynDNS service between the two of them.  Now the issue I'm running into is the rails project (a simple hello page to start) works off my no-IP domain, but when I go to my actual domain (with the no-IP domain as a forwarding address) I get a blank page, Looking at the source I see that it's been put into a frameset, and is empty.

I am relatively new to DNS but an hour of searching I *believe* my issue is with how my DNS records are set up (CNAME vs A), but sadly don't know the details on one compared to the other.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue so I can view my rails apps on my domain instead of being forced to view it from no-IP, or straight from my IP:3000?